# Non-deterministic algorithm to check if a list has some given value

Tags: complexity-theory, nondeterminism

I know that I can build a non-deterministic algorithm with a `CHOICE` function that verifies if a value `x` is in an array in O(1) time complexity.

The usual algorithm to do that is

```
find (A, x)
    j = CHOICE(1, .. , A.length)
    if A[j] == x
        return VALID
    return FAIL
```

But, it works because we are able to access the position `j` directly, in constant time.

So, if I change the problem: instead of an array A, use a linked-list L, then, how can I construct my non-deterministic algorithm using the `CHOICE` function to check if a value `x` is in L or not ?

Will it still have O(1) time complexity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only way you have to access the last element is to step through the whole list, one item at a time, you can't possibly use less than $O(n)$ time, even nondeterministically. If you used less than that, none of the paths through the computation would be able to access the end of the list, so none of them would be able to check whether it contained the desired entry.

Comment: Let's say I have to traverse the list one by one, starting from the first element. But, could I say something like: "Let S be the set of memory address of each node in the list", then, use CHOICE function to choose the right address?

Comment: I just don't know what is the power I have with this CHOICE function... I can use it with any set I want?

Comment: @VitorLima Sure, if you had the set of memory addresses in a list, you could choose from that. But how are you going to obtain that set without traversing the list?

Comment: So, this is the point, I have to supose I will build the set from the arguments I receive, right? Can't I  just create the set I want and use CHOICE function ?

Comment: If you can explain how to create a set, you can certainly choose from it nondeterministically. If you can't create it, how could you possibly use it?

Comment: @VitorLima if you're asking such questions, you have to define what you mean by "list". If all that's given is the address of its head and a function to get the next node of any given node, then a simple adversary argument rules out any O(1) implementations. However, if you can non-deterministically access (read and write) the whole memory space, I think you can probably do logarithmic time...

Comment: @jkff If I could read the entire memory space, then CHOICE function would find the right memory address and the algorithm would run in O(1). But I understood the arguments presented by David Richerby, I can't use CHOICE with something I don't have, it means I need first construct the set...

Comment: With reading the entire memory space you would also need to check that the memory cell you found is actually a node of your list.

Comment: @jkff And that it contains the data item, rather than the pointer to the next/previous node. So, yeah, applying a choice function to the whole of the memory is unlikely to have the right effect.